# Adding a linear effect from an lapply function in R

Tags: r, apply

I'm simulating data for an analysis. I was successful to generate all my values (different populations in different years using an lapply function). But I'm not able to include a linear effect in my simulation.

```
set.seed(1234567890)
year = 2000:2009
x = year - 1999
```

Here I'm creating the nb.ind.per.y variable which is the number of individuals per year (for a total of 10 years).

```
nb.id.per.y = abs(round(rnorm(length(x),10,4)))
year.pop = rep(x,nb.id.per.y)
sp = rep("potatoes",length(year.pop))
```

This is where I'm not able to include a linear effect. I'd like to add this effect in the function definition in the lapply function. As you see here, the "y" is referring to the mean in each year. So the idea would be to add a linear effect of the mean in the population as a function of "year" from 1 to 10.

```
l=lapply(as.list(nb.id.per.y),
         function(x,y) {rnorm(x,y,1)},y = c(15))
df = data.frame(year.pop,sp,unlist(l))
```

Here you can draw the figure:

```
mean.year = unlist(lapply(l, mean))

x = as.numeric(levels(as.factor(df$year.pop)))
y = mean.year
range.x = c(min(x)-se,max(x)+se)
range.y = c(min(y)-se,max(y)+se)
stderr <- function(x) sqrt(var(x,na.rm=TRUE)/length(na.omit(x)))
se = stderr(y)
mean = mean(y)
plot(NA,
     type = "p",
     ylim = range.y,
     xlim = range.x,
     xaxt="n",
     main = "yo",
     xlab = "Site Category",
     ylab = "Mean")
axis(side = 1, at = x, labels = levels(c("yo","man")), cex.lab =1, cex.axis =1)
segments(x, y-se,x, y+se)
epsilon = 0.02
segments(x-epsilon,y-se,x+epsilon,y-se);segments(x-epsilon,y+se,x+epsilon,y+se)
points(x,y, pch=21,bg="red")
```

This is generating this image:

[image]

In the end, I'd like to set a slope affecting the mean of the population across years. How could I do this?

I've tried modifying the lapply:

```
l=lapply(as.list(nb.id.per.y),
         function(x,y) {rnorm(x,y,1)},y = c(1,15))
```

You should get this `l` values (part of it):

```
[[1]]
 [1]  3.34534591 16.93968081  0.37366590 14.84108107
 [5] -0.03408859 15.55442569  1.24930537 16.63994982
 [9]  2.38526581 16.55218193  2.22460991 15.22144785
[13]  1.58081304 15.45406433  0.87557671

[[2]]
 [1] -0.2956652 14.5252330  1.2797953 13.8756383  0.8224261
 [6] 14.8291471  0.2462429 13.5690782  1.5046292 14.0552520
[11] -1.0633752 15.7247725  2.4286999 15.7909396

[[3]]
 [1]  2.0249932 15.8087818  0.9897400 12.2642919  0.8469250
 [6] 15.0890761 -0.9882836 16.4226261  1.0307310 14.1401613
[11]  0.4658036 13.2384317

[[4]]
[1] -0.06553609 15.73054614
```

But when modifying the y = c(1,15), it modifies repeats the mean values for the number of values in the nb.id.per.y object. 
E.g. [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgB3J.png)] 1.3, 14.3, 1.0, 15.6 => [[2]] 1.1, 13.4, 0.8, etc.

But I'd like something more like:

```
[[1]] 1.3, 1.2, 1.0, 1.6 => [[2]] 14.3, 13.4, 15.7, etc.
```

In case you're wondering the linear effect here:

```
abline(lm(y~x))
summary(lm(y~x))
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.43777 -0.12291 -0.04194  0.13391  0.44878 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 15.25837    0.20265  75.293 1.08e-12 ***
x           -0.02263    0.03266  -0.693    0.508    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2967 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.05661,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.06131 
F-statistic:  0.48 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.508
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your `l` value. Please test at same seed. I get `#l[[1]] [1]  3.34534591 16.93968081  0.37366590 14.84108107 -0.03408859 15.55442569  1.24930537 16.63994982 ...`

Comment: You're right! It was just an example of what it's doing, and what I expect to see. I edited the question so that it's easier to understand

Comment: You did not modify the expected output. How does the current relate to expected?